# javascript add class to a class based on radio select

Tags: javascript, custom-selectors

i'm not that well versed with javascript so i'm looking for some help. I am looking for a way to apply a class to the main class of the following block via javascript in opencart

```
<div class="mainclass">

    <div class="childclass">
    ....
    <input type="radio" ..../>

    <?php } else { ?>
   ....
```

using the following code of javascript works but works only on the childclass and i want it to apply to mainclass. i can see that the code basically say to apply to the parent of the input so its correct. but how do i extend or climb up so that in applies to the mainclass?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input').click(function () {
$('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("checked");
$('input:checked').parent().addClass("checked");
});
$('input:checked').parent().addClass("checked");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `parent()` to `parents()` and add `.mainclass` to `parents()`.
You then search for a parent with `class = mainclass` and apply the class `checked` to that `div`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').click(function () {
        $('input:not(:checked)').parents('.mainclass').removeClass("checked");
        $('input:checked').parents('.mainclass').addClass("checked");
    });
    $('input:checked').parents('.mainclass').addClass("checked");
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/fam04sro/1/